# Click link in Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, vba, explorer

I've got a macro that I can use to log in to a website and authenticate myself, now I just need to add a section to click a button (which will download a .csv for me).

Here's the login code:

```
Sub WebLogin()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "www.MYSITE.com"
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    .document.all.Item("edit-name").Value = "MY EMAIL"
    .document.all.Item("edit-pass").Value = "MY PASSWORD"
    .document.forms(0).submit


    Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

  End With

End Sub
```

So, that works fine. Once I'm logged in, here's the info for the button I'm trying to press:

```
<input name="_qf_GPDetail_submit_csv" value="Export to CSV" type="submit"  id="_qf_GPDetail_submit_csv" class="form-submit">
```

If anyone could help me out with a bit of code to click this, that'd be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
IE.document.all("_qf_GPDetail_submit_csv").Click
```

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GswfT0Mrr5M) is a pretty good tutorial on the basics of Internet Explorer Automation.  It got me an initial start.

Comment: If this answer helped you than can you pls [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so that other will know you have the answer now.